# How to retrieve specific values from a list in AngularFire2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have a Firebase Realtime Database that looks like this:

```
Items:
    Object0:
        value1: "Foo-0"
        value2: "Bar-0"
    Object1:
        value1: "Foo-1"
        value2: "Bar-1"
    ...
```

... and so on, cut it down to simplify. Every "ObjectX" contains exactly the same structure,
like value1, value2... The only difference between them is the values of value1, value2.

I need to get value1 from each of the objects.
I can do that now by getting each object and assigning the values to a variable:

```js
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
...
export class FooComponent{
  objectOne: ObjectModel = <ObjectModel>{};
  objectTwo: ObjectModel = <ObjectModel>{};

  constructor(private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.firebase
      .object('/Items/Object0')
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe((objectm: ObjectModel ) => {
        this.objectOne = objectm; }

    this.firebase
      .object('/Items/Object1')
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe((objectm: ObjectModel ) => {
        this.objectTwo = objectm; }

  valueOne = this.objectOne.value1; //"Foo-0"
  valueTwo = this.objectTwo.value1; //"Foo-1"
  }
}
```

```js
export interface ObejctModel {
    value1: string;
    value2: string;   
  }
```

I imagine there is a way easier way to do this using `firebase.list('/Items')` instead of `firebase.object`, but I can't
seem to find any solution that works for me. Can anyone help me refactor this code so it
only uses 1 list instead of 2 (or more) objects?

Also, I must assign the values to variables in typescript, not the usual `{{ items | async }}` in the template approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
this.firebase.list('/Items').valueChanges().subscribe(items => {
     console.log(items);  
     items.forEach(values=>{ console.log(values) });
    });
```

The `items` will contain all the objects and the values in your database. You can also use `forEach` to iterate inside the array, that way you can access `value1` and `value2` without knowing the keys `(Object0 and Object1)`.

Comment: Yes, this works, but how do I then assign a value in items to a variable? I imagined something like `this.SomeVariable = items.Object0.value1`, but this doesn't even seem to be close to how it actually works.

Comment: what are you getting in the log? can you post the array that you get here in the comment

Comment: ```(2) [{…}, {…}]
Object0:
value1: "Foo-0"
value2: "Bar-1"
__proto__: Object
Object1:
value1: "Foo-1"
value2: "Bar-1"
__proto__: Object```

Comment: I tried `console.log(items[0])` and got only Object0, then I tried `console.log(items[0][0])` and got undefined instead of "Foo-0"

Comment: what you can do also is to loop inside the array, so like this `items.forEach(values=>{ console.log(values) });` you should have all the values inside the `console.log`

Comment: No the `items.Object0.value1` approach fails to compile: `"," expected`

Comment: console.log(items[0])` will give you Object0 `console.log(items[1])` will give you Object1 `console.log(items[0].value1)` will give you Foo-0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195503/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-beist-beistson).